# Is there a built-in function for a 3-cased if (less than zero, greater than zero, zero)?

Tags: c#, math

I would like to ask if there's a built-in C# statement that would allow me to write the following with less lines of code:

```
float fH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"); //doesn't really matter where this comes from, but in this case, it's the user's input on a joystick

if (fH < 0)
{
    fH = -1;
}
else if (fH > 0)
{
    fH = 1;
}
else
{
    //don't change anything
}
```

As far as I know, I can't use

```
fH = if(...)
```

because this would only allow for 2 cases while I need 3 cases (smaller than 0, bigger than 0 or 0).

Comment: If the code is otherwise working as expected, I would consider posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com to get their opinion.

Comment: `if` isn't a function to begin with.  C# does have a ternary operator that works much like one, though.

Comment: `fH = (fH < 0) ? -1 : (fH > 0) ? 1 : fH;` Have fun!

Comment: If your else doesn't do anything, why do you need an else?

Comment: fH = fH.CompareTo(0);

Comment: Or, just for the sake of it: `fH = Math.Sign(fH);` But that is not a "3-cased if", well, you can't have everything... ;-)

Comment: @John I just wanted to express that I would also need this third case, not just the first two.

Comment: What does the third case do? "//don't change anything" suggests it doesn't do anything, as does the fact that you have accepted jonsca's answer. With the code you have provided, removing the "else" block will produce the exact same result as including it because there is no code inside the block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Math.Sign](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sign?view=netframework-4.7.2) will return whether the input is positive, negative, or 0 with only a single statement (no real need for the `if` at all).

```
Math.Sign(-2) 
-1
Math.Sign(-3.3)
-1
Math.Sign(3)
1
Math.Sign(0)
0
```

It returns an `int32`, which you can reassign back to your `float` as you were doing.

`fH = Math.Sign(fH);`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if my answer is what you needed, but you can  simplify your code into one line code.

```
if (fH < 0)
{
    fH = -1;
}
else if (fH > 0)
{
    fH = 1;
}
else
{
    //don't change anything
}
```

Turn the code above into one line code below.

```
fH = (fH < 0) ? -1 : ((fH > 0) ? 1 : 0);
```

The `else` part in your code mentions that `fH` value doesn't change. It is only executable if `fH` value is 0. So, I put the zero value at the end of my one line code.